# C++ static member initialization order

Tags: c++

I have a code which has been in use for a long time which has a scenario like following.

There are two classes, `A` and `B`.

`A` class has a public static variable `static B* pB;`

`B` class has a static object of itself (`static B instance;`).

In `B` constructor I set `A::pB = this;`

My question is, since static variable initialization order is undefined, if `b::instance` got initialized before `A::pB`, making `B` constructor to get called first and it tries to set `A::pB` which is uninitialized yet, could it lead to a problem?

My current code runs without any unexpected behavior. Wanted to find out whether it is just my luck or not

(Initialization of `A::pB` and `B::instance` happens in different translation units)

Comment: "The tragedy is that you have a 50%-50% chance of dying"[C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/static-init-order.html)

Comment: @Shan: Compared to the normal 100% chance of dying, that's nice. I'll take the chance! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three parts to initialization, zero initialization,
static initialization and dynamic initialization.  (Zero
initialization is actually part of static initialization, but
it's often convenient to keep them separate.)  They occur in
that order.

If you don't specify any initialization for `static B* A::pb;`,
it will be zero initialized (before anything else), and nothing
else.  If you specify a constant initializer, e.g.

```
B* A::pb = nullptr;
```

, that will also occur before any dynamic initialization.

What happens in a constructor is dynamic initialization, so
there should be no problem with your code unless `A::pb` also
has dynamic initialization, something like:

```
B* A::pb = someFunctionReturningABStar();
```

And finally: the default constructor for pointer is trivial; the
pointer is effectively "constructed" when the program is loaded,
before any code is executed.  So there could never be a problem
due to assigning to `pB` in a constructor.  The only problem
could occur if there was dynamic initialization of the pointer,
which might occur after the assignment in the constructor of
`B::instance`, and overwrite it.

And of course, until `B::instance` is constructed, any other
code will see a null pointer in `A::pb`.